# Error when assigning NSString variable in a block

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

```
    - (NSString *) geocodeAddressFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
    {
        CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
        __block NSMutableString * address = [NSMutableString string];  
        geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) 
         {
             if (error) {     
                 NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No results were found" message:@"Try another search" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                 alert.show;
                 return;
             }
             if ([placemarks count]>0) 
             {   
                 NSLog([placemarks description]);
                 CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                 NSLog(placemark.locality);
//This line makes an error
                 [address initWithString:placemark.locality];**
             }
         }];
        return address;
    }
```

Got following runtime error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** initialization method
>   -initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class __NSCFString: Create a concrete instance!'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never call 'initWithString:' without a matching alloc. Looks more like what you want is `[address setString:placemark.locality]`

Comment: It stops crashing, but address is nil:(

Comment: I found that block completes after function, that's why NSString is empty. Can you please advice anything?

Answer (score 3):

You have already initialized `address` with this line `[NSMutableString string];` so your call to `[address initWithString:placemark.locality];` is trying to initialize an already initialized object.

Change this:

```
[address initWithString:placemark.locality];
```

To:

```
[address setString:placemark.locality];
```

---

[NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSString)
[NSMutableString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
[address initWithString:placemark.locality];
```

should be something more like:

```
address = placemark.locality;
```

or

```
[address appendString:placemark.locality];
```

depending on what yu are trying to accomplish.

Comment: After using a block address instance return nil

Answer (score 1):

At this point, your string is already initialized, [NSMutableString string] is a convenience method which essential returns [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease]. You are trying to re init an already inited object, which is bad.

Change that line to [address appendString:placemark.locality];